# Django - Enter a list of values - ManytoManyField

Tags: django, model

I made the supplier field a select dropdown box since I want it to behave that way but it produces an error:  `Enter a list of values`

my model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=250)
    supplier = models.ManytoManyField(Supplier)
```

my form:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'supplier']
    widgets = {
        'supplier': forms.Select()
    }

def clean_supplier(self):
    return [self.cleaned_data['supplier']]]
```

It displays the error: Enter a list of values

Comment: ManytoManyField is for selecting multiple values not a single one.

Comment: There is no such thing as *ManytoManyField* in Django. Your code should throw an error. You may however try *Many**T**oManyField*.

Answer (score 2):

Dropdown doesn't support multiple selection.Use CheckboxSelectMultiple.

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
```

```
class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ['name', 'supplier']
widgets = {
    'supplier': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
}
```

def clean_supplier(self):
    return [self.cleaned_data['supplier']]]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `ManyToManyField` and for some reason you want users to only choose a single option, you can create a custom widget based on the `Select` widget.

This example processes the submitted data in the same way as the [SelectMultiple widget](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/4.0.x/django/forms/widgets.py#L800).

```
from django import forms

class SelectForManyToMany(forms.Select):

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        try:
            getter = data.getlist
        except AttributeError:
            getter = data.get
        return getter(name)


class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'supplier']
        widgets = {
            'supplier': SelectForManyToMany()
        }
```